# Why doesn't C++ unordered_maps with vector values require vector initialization

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I normally like to program in Python, and I noticed in a Leetcode problem solution written in C++ that the `unordered_map<string, vector<string>>` did not require the vectors to be initialized before they were pushed to.

For example, the something like the following code would run successfully in C++

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> example;

example["example_key"].push_back("example_elem");
```

But in Python, similar code would return a KeyError since the list associated with the key has not been initialized

```
example = {}

example["example_key"].append("example_elem")
```

Why does the `unordered_map` not require the vector to be initialized before something is pushed to it?

Comment: `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` create the object with operation `[]` in case it didn't exist previously. Python on the other hand, has no idea what kind object you are going to store in the dictionary, it can be anything, so default construction isn't possible by any means.

Comment: That's a feature of the `[]` operator in map/unordered_map that automagically inserts a default-value when necessary... aka the greatest newbie trap in all of C++ :)  https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That's a great talk! I'm still pretty sure it's an asan false positive. :)

Comment: For a Python comparison, the behavior of `std::unordered_map` is closer to the `defaultdict`. (Although you're limited in what your default value can be.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at

> `std::unordered_map<...>::operator[]`  Inserts a `value_type` object constructed in-place... if the `key` does not exist. This function is equivalent to `return this->try_emplace(key).first->second;`. (since C++17)

Note that maps also offer an `at` member which does the bounds checking.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at

> `std::unordered_map<...>::at` Returns a reference to the mapped value of the element with key equivalent to `key`. If no such element exists, an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown.